# Как сгруппировать несколько колонок по одинаковым значениям и сделать sum и count в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть df, с такими данными:

| name_0 | name_1 | name_2 | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Катя | Ира | Аня | 1 |
| Ира | Лена | Катя | 0 |
| Настя | Оля | Катя | 2 |

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу понять, как сгруппировать колонки и посчитать sum и count, чтобы получить новый df следующего вида:

| name | sum_day | count_name | count_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Катя | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| Ира | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Настя | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Лена | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| Оля | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Аня | 1 | 1 | 3 |

Comment: А что в столбце count_day? сумма всех дней независимо от имени(1+0+2=3) или это просто количество дней(другими словами количиство строк в столбце day в оригинальном датафрейме, 3 строки)?

Comment: количество строк

Comment: Большое спасибо!! Оба способа работают!

Comment: Тогда отметьте пожалуйста ответ gord1402 галочкой, чтоб вопрос стал решенным)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью `.groupby`. Вот пример:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Создаем исходный DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_0': ['Катя', 'Ира', 'Настя'], 
                   'name_1': ['Ира', 'Лена', 'Оля'], 
                   'name_2': ['Аня', 'Катя', 'Катя'], 
                   'day': [1, 0, 2]})

# Объединяем столбцы name_0, name_1, name_2 в один столбец name
df = df.melt(id_vars='day', value_vars=['name_0', 'name_1', 'name_2'])
df.rename(columns={'value': 'name'}, inplace=True)
df.drop('variable', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Группируем по именам
grouped = df.groupby('name').agg({'day': 'sum', 'name': 'count'}).rename(columns={'day': 'sum_day', 'name': 'count_name'})

result = grouped.sort_values('count_name', ascending=False)

print(result.to_markdown())
```

Comment: Классный способ, я до `melt` чет не додумался)

Answer (score 1):

Можно разделить датафрейм на 3 поддатафрейма для каждого столбца `name_x`, а затем обьеденить в 1 датафрейм из 2 столбцов, а далее использовать `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_0':['Катя', 'Ира', 'Настя'],
                   'name_1':['Ира', 'Лена', 'Оля'],
                   'name_2':['Аня', 'Катя', 'Катя'],
                   'day':[1, 0, 2]})

df_0 = df[['name_0', 'day']].copy()
df_1 = df[['name_1', 'day']].copy()
df_2 = df[['name_2', 'day']].copy()

df_0  = df_0.rename(columns={'name_0': 'name'})
df_1  = df_1.rename(columns={'name_1': 'name'})
df_2  = df_2.rename(columns={'name_2': 'name'})

df_all = pd.concat([df_0, df_1], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
df_all = pd.concat([df_all, df_2], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

df_group = df_all.groupby('name').agg(['sum', 'count']).reset_index().copy()
df_group = df_group.rename(columns={'sum': 'sum_day', 'count': 'count_name'})

df_group['count_day'] = len(df['day'])

df_group
```